# Как парсить библиотекой simplehtmldom?

Tags: php

я убил на это месяцы, и искал в интернете, и сам пытался решать, и методом тыка перепробовал, но все никак...
Почему эта библиотека не может найти текст в блоке твита?
(на самом деле, у меня много вопросов, но все они примерно одинаковы)

```
<?php
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/src/simple_html_dom.php");
  $data = $_GET;

  $user = $data['user'];
  $path = 'https://twitter.com/'.$user;

  $html = file_get_html($path);

  $posts = $html->find('li p.tweet-text');

  echo $posts->outertext; //выводит пустоту

?>
```

[сама библиотека](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Надо начинать с того, что эта библиотека не всегда создаст вам дерево, поэтому надо смотреть, а есть ли что-то в `$html`.

Comment: все аналогичные либы требуют правильный DOM. а это не всегда так. я потому использую регулярные выражения

Comment: @qwrtam попробуйте вместо `$html = file_get_html($path);` 
использовать `$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents($path));`

Answer (score 0):

Да потому что в твоем случае $posts это объект с твиттами, сами твитты надо выводить перебором. Всё работает - и либа правильная (только чутка тормознутая) и DOM валидный.

```
foreach( $posts as $item){
    echo $item->outertext;
}
```